# getting the most recent 'created' row (spaning tables)

Tags: python, django

If I have the following tables:

```
class Potter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Sculpture(models.Model):
    potter = models.ForeignKey(Potter)
    created = models.DateTimeField()

class Vase(models.Model):
    potter = models.ForeignKey(Potter)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
```

How can I find the most recent `Sculpture` or `Vase` for a certain `Potter` with the minimum amount of database hits *(i.e. this is an oversimplification of my problem, I have more then two tables referencing `Potter`)* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a view where you receive a potter id:

```
ordered_sculptures = Sculpture.objects.filter(potter=potter).order_by('-created') 
ordered_vases = Vase.objects.filter(potter=potter).order_by('-created')
```

EDIT: I may have misread something, so if you want the latest using the querysets, you can just reference the first element of each queryset (if they exist):

```
latest = ordered_sculptures[0]
```

Same applies for vases.

Reference: [django order_by in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Another approach, if you defined your default ordering for those querysets, is the reverse method:

```
latest = Sculpture.objects.filter(potter=potter).reverse()[0]
```

Comment: So do I have to get the `created` values for both and then compare them?

Comment: Yes, indeed!!!!!! <<--- random chars just to fill out the minimum chars requirement for commenting